# Is there a way to reload turbolinks data-turbolinks-permanent?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have an app and it uses data-turbolinks-permanent under the render like this:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 100px;" >
   <%= yield %>
</div>
<div class="media-player" data-turbolinks-permanent id="music-player">

   <div class="audio-player">
      <!-- Audio Player -->
   </div>
</div>
```

And when a user selects a new song, it needs to refresh this part. How can I do that while keeping it permanent for every other link type?

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks also have `data-turbolinks-temporary`, you could add it to `audio-player`

```
<div class="audio-player" id="the_player" data-turbolinks-temporary>
   <!-- Audio Player -->
</div>
```

On turbolinks-classic this is not working, there is a issue already:

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/674

Comment: It seems to work the same as data-turbolinks-permanent. It won't change songs.